# What is the relationship between App.vue and index.html?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I created an application scaffold using `vue-cli`. There is no clear explanation (AFAICT) that shows the relationship between the generated files: `App.vue` and `index.html`.

It seems from the resulting pages that `index.html` contains the HTML generated from `App.vue`. However, both of the above named files have HTML with a `div` element having `id="app"`. What is the purpose of each of these files? and why do they both have an element with the same ID, since an element ID is supposed to be a unique identifier in a document?

#### /public/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title>sample</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but sample doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

#### /src/App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </div>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
#nav {
  padding: 30px;
}

#nav a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

#nav a.router-link-exact-active {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please, list all relevant files. The question should be understandable without using external sources. Even if the thing you describe can be replicated with vue-cli now, this may change in future.

Comment: Generally, the index.html is the actual webpage responsible for loading the script, which App.vue is compiled into. Browsers don't natively run Vue code, nor do they typically run JS on its own, so you need an actual HTML document to house your Vue app. As for the div#app, the one in the html is the root element of your app. Vue overrides this element, via `new Vue({...}).$mount('#app')` so if you need a div with an id of `app` in the app itself, you need to recreate it in your template.

Comment: It's merely a coincidence that the elements have the same ID. You could name them differently. In fact, no ID is needed in `App.vue`, but the ID there is used for styling. You could instead use `class="app"`, and change the style selector from `#app` to `.app`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

renders `App` component to `#app` DOM element, i.e. replaces `<div id="app"></div>` that is specified in index.html with `App` rendered template.

It could be `<div id="app"></div>` in index.html and `<div id="rendered-app"></div>` in  App.vue `<template>`. That both index.html and App.vue contain `<div id="app"></div>` isn't a requirement but this makes sense because original `div` is replaced and it's guaranteed there's only one element with `app` id.